# Is there any offline manuals for special characters used in terminal?

Tags: bash, man, special-characters, documentation

We can find help regarding most commands like `echo` ,`cp`, `mv`, `wget` using `man` .

But can I find manuals for special characters used for operations like piping(| symbol)? If there's none, is there any official documentation on this?

Comment: Something like [Shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) ?

Comment: Yes. I mean symbols used in shell. I didn't mentioned it clearly in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because these special characters all belong to induvidual, different programs.

Although many of them have similar meanings, it can sometimes - at least a little bit - differ. For example, `\` has the same effect in a bash command line, as in a grep, but it escapes different things.

To get the list of the meanings of the special characters, you have to find them the corresponding manual pages (or other documentations).

As you are likely learning the Linux command line, you will most likely find special characters in

- bash
- grep
- awk
- sed

programs.

It could be useful to read also the meaning of the special characters in regular expression (google for "regexp tutorial").

Comment: "...As you are likely learning the Linux command line..." - A very good guess.Yes, I'm learning linux. I'll check regexp tutorials.